when there are N instances of the same, are there N or N-1 repeats?
I am looking for an appropriate name for a certain number N in a software user interface. N is the number of identical instances of object A in object B. Could we call it nCopies or nRepeats or nRepetitions? Couldn't that be misunderstood as N-1 because there are not N copies, but one original and N-1 copies? Is there an unambiguous term for N?

“Instances” is an option.

"Number of", "Count", "Occurrences", "Frequency", etc.

Does B contains an original object and its N-1 clones ? or simply N items using the same instantiation process ?

@Graffito: the latter.

@Xanne that sounds like an answer!

@StuartF That sounds like an answer!

'Reproductions' covers N-1, as does 'copies'.

The term "duplicate" could, in the proper context, make the idea of n-1 reproductions (copies, esp. of a work of art) irrelevant, although both interpretations are allowed.

(SOED) duplicate 2 Either of two or more specimens of a thing exactly or virtually alike; a thing which is the exact counterpart of another, regarded as an original.


Yes; 'duplicate' has conflicting definitions.
